# how to do ssh from the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have tried to run the following command from command line and it works perfect as expected

```
ssh someIP "java -jar /path/program.jar "someIP""
```

but when i wrote in the bash script as following:

```
 ssh $f1 \"java -jar /path/program.jar   \"$f1\"\" ;
```

where $f1 is the ip address. it does not work and gives me the error:

> bash: java -jar /path/program.jar someIP: No such file or directory

I tried to echo the ssh command and it is correct and i just copied the echoed command and pasted on the command prompt and it has worked. So I am now confuse, what is wrong in the bash script that I am missing

Comment: When you launch a `SSH` command, this does not read the `.profile` of the remote computer, which might cause the `java` program not to be found. I'd advise you to add the `.profile` reading to your `SSH` command and try again. (Unfortunately, I don't know how to add this, otherwise this would be an answer instead of a comment :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try EOF.

```
ssh $1 << EOF
            #commands here
EOF
```

After the commands are done the connection is severed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try not to escape.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1 "java -jar program.jar "$1""
```